# Uploading Multiple Attachments into Access and allocating automatically

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Two days on and I'm ripping my hair out.

I need to upload hundreds of 'png' attachments into a table (i.e. not one by one to each account code) where they automatically find the relevant account code in the table by matching the account code to the attachment file name.

Alternatively I need to upload all the attachments to a single place and then have a search query that allocates these attachments to their specific account codes in a table.

I have been able to come up with a query that allocates ALL of the attachments to ALL of my relevant account codes  but cannot allocate specific attachments using the data filename for reference to a specific account code.

I have also been able to create a form that shows the relevant attachment under the data filename but this will not open from this field when I double click it. When I open the attachment itself from the form it just gives the 'manage attachment' box showing every single attachment for me to select the one I want. This is of no use for my customer.

I'm sure it has to be simple but I have spent ages on this so can anyone please help.

Graham

Comment: Are these any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902775/display-multiple-attachments-in-microsoft-access-2010-forms-and-reports/13904836#13904836 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223266/how-to-copy-the-contents-of-an-attached-file-from-an-ms-access-db-into-a-vba-var/14235764#14235764 ?

Comment: Thanks Remou

I saw your first response before writing this and that is why I added the bit that says

'I have also been able to create a form that shows the relevant attachment under the data filename but this will not open from this field when I double click it. When I open the attachment itself from the form it just gives the 'manage attachment' box showing every single attachment for me to select the one I want. This is of no use for my customer.'

I really thought I had found the answer when I saw your horse pictures but how do you just get the pictures in the second column to open?

Ta

Comment: I mentioned the links because I am not at all sure I understand you, and what you mean by open. What I think you may want is a single form or continuous form with images that opens on clicking a link of some description. This is easy enough with OpenForm. If this is not what you want, can you say exactly what you mean by "open", do you mean in an image editor?

Comment: Hi Remou, I woke up this morning realising that I had been focussing on 'opening' the data image when of course all I had to do was to enlarge it to the size of the screen and to write a Me! filter to select the ones I wanted from the form. I'm sure I am capable of this and must just apologise for wasting your time. However it was your initial answer that got me here so I am happy for you to confirm the above as an answer so I can call you a Guru.

Comment: No problem, things get a bit weird after a number of hours on a project. Thanks for the offer, but I'll leave it with the original answer, and you are welcome to call me grr. :)