# display multiple attachment in MS Access web

Tags: ms-access, web

I would like to display all the attached documents on a record in a repeating form.  The answer posted by Remou works (link below), but not on a web Access db.

[Display multiple attachments in microsoft access 2010 forms and reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902775/display-multiple-attachments-in-microsoft-access-2010-forms-and-reports)

Does anyone know of a way for me to do this either in a report or a form or do I have to click on the attachment window every time I want to see what documents are attached?

Cheers,

Tony